# BizTalk Message Status: Queued (awaiting processing)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

we have a biztalk server 2010 standard edition in use to route messages to a dozen partners.

For a few partners we directly route the incoming messages to the partners, only including some maps to transform the message to the desired format.

For other partners we have an orchestration in place to batch the messages together to reduce the number of files we have to transmit (especially if we connect via FTP). These orchestrations run from 1 am to 11 pm, sending out the batched files every 20 minutes or after X messages. We receive most messages during the early morning.

This worked fine in the past, but suddenly something doesn't work anymore as expected.
When we get the messages starting from 1am in the morning, we can see that these batch files are sent out to the partners till about 2am, then it suddenly stops working. After restarting the host instance of these orchestrations, we can see that biztalk continues to send out the batched files, but only for another 10 minutes or so and we have to restart the instance again.

We see that we have more than 50k messages with the status "Queued (awaiting processing)". After a couple of restarts and no more queued messages, everything works fine througout the day (but we have less traffic during the day)

The behaviour started after a deployment, but the only change was in a assembly that we call within one of the orchestrations, but the change was very minor (just a change in an if-condition).

I checked the applications logs, but there is no hint that any throttling kicked in nor is any error mentioned in the logs.

Do you have any idea where I may find some information what's going on?

Your help is most appreciated!

Thank you and best regards
Michael

-- 2013-08-23:

I just installed CU6 on our acceptance system and sent 5000 Messages to BizTalk. 
5 Orchestrations (one per party that requires that we send them the messages in batches) started and after a moment I see these queued messages:

[image: Queued Messages]

I have a send file port that writes the batched messages to the file system. It worked fine for about 4 minutes, the orchestration created a file as soon as 100 messages had arrived. Afterwards it waited the 10 minute timeout and created the next file, but with less messages even thought there were a few thousand messages left....

[image: File System]

Comment: Is it the Send Port instance that is stuck in the "Queued (awaiting processing)" state, or the Orchestration instance? Are you using ordered delivery in any way? Are you using Dynamic Ports?

Comment: Hi Nick, yes we use ordered delivery because we use a sequential convoy to batch the messages together within an orchestration. The orchestration instance is in status "running". We use direct port binding. The messages itself are in status "queued" and waiting for the orchestration to pick them up.

Comment: Does the singleton orchestration instance ever terminate by itself or does it just run forever?

Comment: the orchestration instance terminates at about 11pm and starts again with the first message in the morning at about 1am

Comment: Have you tried reverting back to the old state (before deployment) to make sure no "damage" was done via this way?

Comment: no I haven't, but a couple of colleagues checked the condition I changed and we can't see any issue with the code change

Answer (score 3):

MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559609.aspx) suggests that the "Queued (awaiting processing)" state relates to messages that are 'in an ordered delivery scenario when the preceding message is being retried by the ordered delivery send port'.

I do not know whether you have any preceding messages within your ordered delivery scenario that are attempting to retry, but this might be worth checking when you encounter this issue.