# BizTalk Message Queued (awaiting processing)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am sending a message to BizTalk receive location and it is stuck somewhere. Querying the Tracked Message events gives me following:

[image: It was recognised as a proper XML and matched some XSD]

And when i query all in-progress service instances, i finding my orchestration in state "Ready to run":

[image: Ready to run]

The Service details tells me that the message was queued and awaits processing:

[image: Queued]

In a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054877/biztalk-message-status-queued-awaiting-processing) was suggested that "The message is in an ordered delivery scenario when the preceding message is being retried by the ordered delivery send port."

The problem is that i don't have ordered delivery in my applications.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Orchestration will be configured against a Host - check that the Host has a Host Instance that is in the running/started state.